# Adding Reference in Vb6- MSR and DAO 3.6

Tags: vb6

Maybe i don't have any knowledge of how referencing works in VB6. I have an application written on visual basic 6. I've added Microsoft Scripting Runtime and Data Access Object 3.6 as references. I wanna know which component should be placed in others systems to prevent issues related to these two references. I mean if the user has windows XP, Vista,7 or 8 does my application will run correct in that versions of windows? (considering these two references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your clients install the EXEs created by Microsoft:

- For Microsoft Scripting Runtime, check out the "Cause" Section of [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254166).
- For DAO, check out the resolutiion section of [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280513).

Comment: Thank you ray. I have another question. I use MSR only for getting file size( like this Set f = fso.GetFile(App.Path & "/dd.text")    If f.Size=1000 .... ). Is there any other way to get file size with fewer limitations rather than the Microsoft scripting runtime?

Comment: @DavidPeterson "FileLen" is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to include DAO 3.6 redistributable files, as explained on the [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233002); However, your application will work properly on all of these target Windows versions, if no other potential issues exists (e.g. other incompatible used ActiveX control)